# Sql join does not return some rows with groupBy

Tags: sql, sum, left-join

I am trying to learn sql.I do some practices.I created a table which called Student.

```
Id | Name   | Amount
1  | Jone   | 100
2  | Jack   | 200
3  | Emily  | 300
4  |Haaland | 500
7  |Ted     | 700
```

I also created Orders table like that:

```
 Id | Name    | Amount  | Dıscount
 1  | Jone    | 100     | 10
 2  | Jack    | 112     | 20
 3  | Emily   | 300     | 30
 4  |Haaland  | 500     | 50
 5  |Jack     | 88      | 12
 7  |Ted      | 150     | 235
```

My query is:

```
select a1.Id Id ,a1.Name Name, a1.Amount Amount , sum(a2.discount) 
from student a1 
  left outer join orders a2 
          on a1.Id=a2.Id 
         and a1.Name=a2.Name 
        and a1.Amount = a2.Amount 
group by a1.Id, a1.Name, a1.Amount
```

Result:

```
Id | Name   | Amount  | Dıscount
 1  | Jone   | 100     | 10    
 3  | Emily  | 300     | 30
 4  |Haaland | 500     | 50
 2  | Jack   | 200     | null
 7  | Ted    | 700     | null
```

I get null value for the jack row.I have to use `a1.Amount=a2.Amount` because I remove amount constraint Ted'discount also appears.

Expected Result :

```
 Id | Name   | Amount  | Dıscount
 1  | Jone   | 100     | 10    
 3  | Emily  | 300     | 30
 4  |Haaland | 500     | 50
 2  | Jack   | 200     | 32
 7  | Ted    |700      | null
```

Comment: I am not sure what should be problem statement. But looking at your result, it seems Jack row has some space or something like this in the name and thats why you cant see Jack row. What do you expect for Jones?

Comment: I want to add jack row but there are two jack rows on orders table.I think it causes problem.

Comment: nope, you are joining on a1.Id=a2.Id, this will result `2  | Jack   | 200` and remove the other row in order table.

Comment: I am sorry.I wrote my question with wrong data.I updated my question.

Comment: What is the logic for wanting the Jack discounts and not wanting the Ted discount? Is it because orders.amount sum to student.amount for Jack but not for Ted?

Comment: I see that you make up tables, so you can practise writing queries. However, the tables don't make too much sense, so you are actually *adding* a problem and writing reasonable queries becomes more difficult. You have a student table. But why does a student have an amount? That seems wrong. You have an orders table and you want to link this to the students (because a student placed that order?). Both tables have an ID that uniquely identifies their rows, but why do you think that a student ID should equal an order ID? The order table should have an own id and an *additional* student_id...

Comment: ... Then, the order table should not contain a student name (because it should just link to a student in the student table and thus get related to the student name). I think you should better look for some database for learners that you can copy or use. Maybe there is even one shipped with your DBMS. Oracle has the so-called scott schema with employees, departments, etc. for instance. Or use an Internet site that comes with an online database like https://sqlzoo.net/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic you want is to pre-aggregate the orders of each name in a subquery, then join by name and amount:

```
select s.id , s.name, s.amount, o.discount
from student s
left join (
    select name, sum(amount) amount, sum(discount) discount 
    from orders 
    group by name
) o on o.name = s.name and o.amount = s.amount
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the confusion?  In one row you have:

```
id    name    amount
2     Jack    200
```

And in the other:

```
id    name    amount
2     Jack    112
```

Your `join` requires equality on all three columns.  The amounts don't match, so there is no match for Jack's row and the amount is null.

Your question is not clear on what you actually want to do, so I'll stop here.

Answer (score 0):

The amount for Jack does not match (200 in Student, 88 and 112 in Orders), so nothing can be joined ON a1.Amount = a2.Amount for that record. However, Please be advised that even if *one* of the values in Amount does match, the GROUP BY function will still not know which Amount you want associated with 'Jack'.